# wmi and network drives

Tags: c#, permissions, wmi, wmi-service

I have an application which uses WMI to do stuff on a remote machine.
One of those things is running a script which writes an output to a file on the hd.

If I choose to save the output on the remote machine's local drives - everything works.
But, if I try saving them on a network drive, even the ones which I have full permissions to - it fails.

After breaking my head, I came up with what I think the problem is. 
Is it possible that the WMI service must have permissions on the network drive in order to perform such actions? And if so, any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What kind of script? Is this not something that you could do easier using PSTools?

Comment: The script is a standard batch script, and I assume I could, but I prefer using this tool, and not external tools.

Comment: How about running a Scheduled Task from the server? that way you just need to use Batch files.

Comment: Umm....that won't help much since I have an entire team who needs access to that application - the times on which they're being run vary...